# Keycloak 3.0 rest api error: UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "access"

Tags: java, rest, api, keycloak

I am using keycloak-admin-client 3.0.0.Final with Keycloak 3.0 server. I am trying to add new redirect urls but I am getting an exception while trying to update client:

```
13:16:47,615 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-3) RESTEASY002005: Failed executing PUT /admin/realms/DecisionSpace_Integration_Server/clients/07e6ecb0-63f0-4dde-8bde-e725c592c9d8: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "access" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.ClientRepresentation), not marked as ignorable (37 known properties: "enabled", "clientAuthenticatorType", "redirectUris", "useTemplateConfig", "clientId", "serviceAccountsEnabled", "authorizationServicesEnabled", "name", "implicitFlowEnabled", "registeredNodes", "nodeReRegistrationTimeout", "publicClient", "attributes", "protocol", "webOrigins", "consentRequired", "protocolMappers", "id", "baseUrl", "surrogateAuthRequired", "adminUrl", "fullScopeAllowed", "frontchannelLogout", "clientTemplate", "directGrantsOnly", "rootUrl", "bearerOnly", "secret", "useTemplateMappers", "notBefore", "useTemplateScope", "standardFlowEnabled", "description", "defaultRoles", "authorizationSettings", "registrationAccessToken", "directAccessGrantsEnabled"])
 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@6d806b95; line: 1, column: 3665] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.idm.ClientRepresentation["access"])
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:184)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
```

I am using this code
https://gist.github.com/imranshafqat/7e636afc8e223203451ab8c3a13b2458

Comment: keycloak-admin-client and keycloak server should same version

Comment: @ravthiru is there any other solution since i've got both client and server version 3.4.3.Final and it still shows me that error

Comment: Which version of server and client you are using, and for which field you are getting the error?

Comment: @ravthiru this is the link of my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858549/error-when-running-keycloak-in-docker